# Texture Mapping with a Circular Texture

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I have a planet texture that I would like to map onto a UV sphere. The texture is a circular texture (I have attached it below).
[image: Planet Texture]
Currently, I've been using a node setup that works for mapping matcaps onto spheres. However, it just causes the texture to be pixelated on the mesh, even when I apply a subsurf modifier.
[image: Nodes and Problem]
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is your sphere smooth shaded ? (in Object mode, W, Shade smooth)

Comment: @thibsert, surely you can turn that into a good answer!

Comment: If that actually answer the question, I will!

Comment: @thibsert some changes in the mapping could do (maybe, i've not done it, and will not)

Answer (score 1):

The texture is only half of the sphere. If you UV-unwrap the half UV sphere by "project from view", e.g. in X direction, it could work, because the texture is itself projected from view - but I haven't tried myself.

Comment: I tried it using object coordinates, and it worked-but now there is a black ring around the sphere. Thanks anyway!